# Java Timezones to milliseconds

Tags: java, time, java-8, milliseconds

I got current IST time and converted it to ET timezone. Then i calculated milliseconds for both. But both give same value. They should give different millisec values, right?
I used following method,

```
EtTimeZone.toInstant().toEpocMillie();
```

Comment: No, milliseconds since epoch is the same in whatever timezone, because epoch is defined as a specific instant in time (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC, to millisecond precision). In fact, milliseconds since epoch doesn't really have a timezone at all - it's just a number of milliseconds since a specific instant in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Epoch time will have same value in multiple timezone's. epoch time is the time in millisec from 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC  . In case of other timezone's starting point is different

In case of IST(UTC+5:30) start point is 1970-01-01 00:05:30.000